# Use the good Syntax for my code

Tags: syntax

I have an error message with my below code but i don't know how to solve it. The problem come from this line `k[d_, p_] = g1-[Ht] - p`, and mathematica cannot execute this line. I am know that the problem come from the syntax . Unfortunately, i can't make the right one.
here below the all  code:

```
 Clear["Global`*"]


c = 0.058;
rc = -0.06;
th = 0.80;


g1[ε_] = 2*(ε + 0.5)*(ε + 0.5);


dmin = 1;
dmax = 3;
pas = 0.01;
dlist = Table[d, {d, dmin, dmax, pas}]
Length[dlist]

f[d_] = Min[{-0.02 + 0.0231397 d, 0.038524}];

rt = Simplify[((1 + rc) (1 - p th ))/(1 - p) - 1]

Ht = (rt - c) d - f[d]

k[d_, p_] = g1-[Ht] - p

For[i = 1, i < Length[dlist] + 1, 
 i++, {Print[i "ème d fixé = ", dlist[[i]]], 
  Print[NSolve[k[dlist[[i]], p] == 0, p, Reals]]}]
```

Can anyone help please? thanks

Comment: The bug is: `[Ht]`. What should this mean?

Comment: Suggestions to improve your code + fixing the error: Instead of `Table[d, {d, dmin, dmax, pas}]` use `Range`, for functions with inputs, instead of `=` use `:=`, Mathematica uses `{}` for lists not `[]`, instead of `k[d_, p_] = g1-[Ht] - p` write `k[d_, p_]:= g1-{Ht} - p`. Also instead of using `For` with `Length[dlist]` and `dlist[[i]]` use `Map` or `MapIndexed`.

Comment: Thanks @BenyIzd. I've tried to change the last part as per your advice. But I had no result. I did'nt undestand how to use the `Map` or `MapIndexed`. Can you please show what you did?

Comment: @DanielHuber`[Ht]`means this equality `Ht = (rt - c) d - f[d]`.

Comment: Do you mean: `k[d_, p_] = g1-Ht - p` ?

Comment: Yes exactly, but as per adviced, i should use `k[d_, p_]:= g1-{Ht} - p`. And you were right because the bug come from this part. But untill now, i don't have the esperted result. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: `MapIndexed[Print[#2[[1]], " ème d fixé = ", #1, " ", NSolve[k[#1, p] == 0, p, Reals]] &, list]`, I was wrong, `{Ht}` in not correct for your purpose. Even `k[d_, p_] := g1 - Ht - p` still is a problem, `g1[]` is a function but you didn't call it, Mathematica will treat that and `Ht` as a variable. Try `k[1, 1]` to see.

Comment: @BenyIzd do you mean `k[1, 1] = g1 - [Ht] - p`? or only ``k[1, 1]`. I've tried both but don't have result.

Answer (score 1):

Is the following what you want?

```
Clear["Global`*"]

c = 58/1000;
rc = -6/100;
th = 8/10;

g1[\[CurlyEpsilon]_] = 
  2*(\[CurlyEpsilon] + 0.5)*(\[CurlyEpsilon] + 0.5);

dmin = 1;
dmax = 3;
pas = 1/100;
dlist = Table[d, {d, dmin, dmax, pas}] // Rationalize;
Length[dlist]

f[d_] = Rationalize[Min[{-0.02 + 0.0231397 d, 0.038524}]];

rt = Simplify[((1 + rc) (1 - p th))/(1 - p) - 1];

Ht = (rt - c) d - f[d];

k[d_, p_] = g1[Ht] - p;

For[i = 1, i < Length[dlist] + 1, 
 i++, {Print[i "ème d fixé = ", dlist[[i]]], 
  Print[NSolve[k[dlist[[i]], p] == 0, p, Reals]]}]
```

The beginning of the out is:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Not exactly, what im looking for is the value of `p`for each `d`present in my `dlist`. So if you run my first code by using `k[d_, p_] = g1[Ht] - p` instead of `k[d_, p_] = g1-[Ht] - p`,the result will appear with a value of `p` for each `d`. But for now, i'm trying to run the same code with an other function, that means `k[d_, p_] = g1-[Ht] - p`. And that was the purpose of my post, beacause when i use `k[d_, p_] = g1-[Ht] - p` the code doesn't run anymore.

Comment: I changed this. But I confused by `k[d_, p_] = g1-[Ht] - p` this is not correct syntax.

Comment: Yes Daniel, the syntax is not correct, and that exactly what i'm trying to solve

Comment: But it is not clear to me what you want.

Comment: @EmilioDas, likely if you use correct syntax whatever you want to do will work. However, as Daniel states, this point of what you want to do is unclear. Please, clarify what the expected behavior should be and why you think your incorrect syntax should be the solution. This will help immensely.

Comment: @EmilioDas, `g1` is defined as a function that requires a variable. So `g1[Ht]` makes sense - `Ht` is the variable passed to `g1`. But `g1-[Ht]` doesn't make sense. Perhaps you mean `g1[Ht]-Ht`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for yours kinds help. Unfortunately i  wasn't clear with my question because `g1` and `[Ht]`are fuctions. So i was trying to compare these functions with an other one wich wasn't define in my previous code. I am so sorry for that misundestanding. nOW I've changed my code and it runs perfectly.